# Stretch an input control to the full width of the parent flex item's container in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I have the following layout.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Comments</div>
    <div class="container p-0">
        <div class="row align-items-center g-0">
            <div class="col-8 align-self-stretch">
                <ig:TextBoxEditor runat="server" ID="txtSearch" TextMode="Search" AutoPostBack="True" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <asp:CheckBoxNoSpan runat="server" ID="cbAdvancedFilters" CssClass="form-check-input" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="OnToggleGridAdvancedFilters" ></asp:CheckBoxNoSpan>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="form-check-label" AssociatedControlID="cbAdvancedFilters">Advanced filters</asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" EnableViewState="True"  class="form-check-input" runat="server" ID="cbPager" role="switch" OnServerChange="OnToggleGridPager"/>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="form-check-label" AssociatedControlID="cbPager">Pager</asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="border border-bottom border-1"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to know how to stretch the element with ID **"txtSearch"** to the full width of the parent DIV element with class "col-8"

I tried to apply a class **"align-self-stretch"** to the DIV element with class **"col-8"**, but it didn't work out

Comment: have you tried using the class `w-100` on the div with the id `txtSearch`?

Comment: I tried to use, it works, but I think it's not correct. There must be some more elegant way to solve this issue without forced solutions

Comment: Do you have any other styles on `txtSearch`? It might be displaying inline

Comment: It's displayed AS IS, just inline element without any additional styles.

Comment: have you tried displaying txtSearch as a block instead of inline?

Comment: It works if I change display mode to block or inline-block and then apply class "w-100", but I'm looking for the most elegant way to fix it. I suppose it's somehow linked to the flex-box model

Comment: Do you have `display: flex;` and `align-items: stretch;` on the `col-8` div?